# jQuery DataTables export pdf cuts off columns

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables

I have a dataset with large number of colums.

When exporting the pdf , columns that dont fit on the page get cut off.

I tried using the 'orientation' and 'page-size' options but its not enough.

```
    buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                }
            ]
```

Ideally it should do one of the following:

1. Fit the data on one page ( making the font really small )
2. Continue the data in another page in the the pdf

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue and haven't found a fix yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i managed to solve this problem with setting option for pdf like

```
 {
                extend : 'pdfHtml5',
                title : function() {
                    return "ABCDE List";
                },
                orientation : 'landscape',
                pageSize : 'LEGAL',
                text : '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"> PDF</i>',
                titleAttr : 'PDF'
            }
```

[image]

became

[image]

Answer (score 13):

thanks @parlad , however Below is the perfect solution -

```
{
            extend : 'pdfHtml5',
            title : function() {
                return "ABCDE List";
            },
            orientation : 'landscape',
            pageSize : 'A0', // You can also use "A1","A2" or "A3", most of the time "A3" works the best.
            text : '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"> PDF</i>',
            titleAttr : 'PDF'
        }
```

**pageSize : 'A0',** does the trick :), but you can also use `A1`, `A2` or `A3`,
Hope it helps to others.

Comment: still 2 columns not coming.

Comment: For anyone who finds "A0" size too small, you can use "A1", "A2", "A3" etc. For me A3 worked.

Comment: @RushabhDave A0 is the largest and A5 is the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

CDN :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,b-1.1.0,b-flash-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,fh-3.1.0,sc-1.4.0/datatables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,b-1.1.0,b-flash-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,fh-3.1.0,sc-1.4.0/datatables.min.js
```

HTML :

```
<h1>Print test</h1>
<div class="data-table-container">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered data-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-right">No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-right">1</td>
        <td>Java</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-right">2</td>
        <td>HTML</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="text-center">footer text</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('table.data-table').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 'no-sort',
    orderable: false
  }],
  dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-6"Bl><"col-sm-6"f>>' +
    '<"row"<"col-sm-12"<"table-responsive"tr>>>' +
    '<"row"<"col-sm-5"i><"col-sm-7"p>>',
  fixedHeader: {
    header: true
  },
  buttons: {
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'print',
      text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print',
      title: $('h1').text(),
      exportOptions: {
        columns: ':not(.no-print)'
      },
      footer: true,
      autoPrint: false
    }, {
      extend: 'pdf',
      text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF',
      title: $('h1').text(),
      exportOptions: {
        columns: ':not(.no-print)'
      },
      footer: true
    }],
    dom: {
      container: {
        className: 'dt-buttons'
      },
      button: {
        className: 'btn btn-default'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr77dgmt/3/)

Comment: It cuts off when I extend your fiddle with more columns and longer row value lengths: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr77dgmt/34/

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, in that case, if you set all the column to equal length, I checked for 16 columns and found it all columns are appearing correctly.

you can set the width manually or you can also set the width dynamically if you are not aware of the number of columns.

add the following line first:

```
doc.content[0].layout = objLayout;
```

Now you can set the table widths different way. Choose the one you want.

Method 1:

```
//For equal column size
doc.content[0].table.widths = ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*","*","*", "*"];
```

Method 2: 
For setting fixed column size if you want to set a fixed width for different different columns:

```
doc.content[0].table.widths = ["5%", "5%", "8%", "8%", "8%", "8%","7%", "7%", "8%", "6%", "8%", "8%","7%", "7%"];
```

Method 3: 
 Dynamically set the equal size (if there are different tables with different number of columns)

```
//Get the column length
var colCount = table.columns().header().length;
//use a loop
for(var col=0;col<colCount;col++)
{
   size[col]='*';
}
doc.content[0].table.widths = size;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  "buttons": [
  {
    extend: 'print',
    text: 'Print',
    title: 'All trucks',
    exportOptions: {
      columns: [0,1]
    },
    footer: true,
    autoPrint: true
  },
  {
    extend: 'excel',
    text: 'Excel',
    title: 'All trucks',
    exportOptions: {
      columns: [0,1]
    },
    footer: true,
    autoPrint: true
  },
  "colvis"]
```