# PDF file gets cropped while exporting from Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function using jQuery for exporting a table in PDF. However each time I export it, the table gets cut and the right side of the columns gets cut. I think it's because my table has a lot of columns, but I still need to show it in the PDF.

How can I fix this issue?

This is the code snippet for converting to pdf.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example_booking').DataTable({
    "order": [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you give a clearer description of what you mean by 'cut'. Is it missing rows, or columns, or cropping an image...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the right side of the table get completely cut from the pdf, and doesnt show any of the columns.

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38958077/519413)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It seems like that does not help aswell, i tried this earlier but it still gives the same output.

Comment: Is it because of excessive number of columns and data or else?, plus you can change the orientation to Landscape of the pdf upon generation in datatables if the case is excessive number of columns and data

Comment: Thank you for the help! The solution @RoryMcCrossan gave worked fine. Was an error from running the javascript file. Thanks again!